# Counting ad clicks and displaying ads every 3 clicks in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, admob, ads

I implemented an `Interstitial Ad` on my Jetpack Compose project with AdMob. It worked perfectly, but I want to make it non-frustrated for users. Users should see the interstitial ad when they click after every 3 times click. For example, he/she clicks, and an interstitial ad will show up, then the following 2 times ad will not shown to the user and this action will happen again and again. How do I implement it on this code base:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val activity = context.findActivity()
MobileAds.initialize(context) {}
var adCount by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}

// my done icon for showing an interstitial ad
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.done),
        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.done_icon),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(20.dp)
            .clickableWithoutRipple {
                if (firstState.text.isEmpty() || secondState.text.isEmpty()) {
                    emptyStateDialogOpened = true
                } else {                            
                    if (activity != null) {
                        showInterstialAd(activity, context)
                    }
                        viewModel.onEvent(MyEvent.SaveCar)
                        }
                }
        )
```

I tried some solutions such as `adCounter` variable, but none of them worked on this Compose project.

Comment: I think you should use time for the rather click counting. I'm using 40 seconds time gap between ```InterStitial Ads``` for  Admob.

Comment: But I don't wanna do it at a certain time. It will affect badly to the user experience. Maybe the user doesn't want to save anything and not pressing the done button, but he/she will see the ad after 40 seconds. That can be very annoying

Comment: I'm using it in my app and getting very good reviews and eCPM. so overall its up to you.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but it is up to the app and developer's choice. Thanks for the suggestion meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

you dont use your adCount, increase the adCount and check if its multiple of 3

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val activity = context.findActivity()
MobileAds.initialize(context) {}

// Initialize the counter
var adCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

// Your done icon for showing an interstitial ad
Icon(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.done),
    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.done_icon),
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(20.dp)
        .clickableWithoutRipple {
            // Increment the counter on every click
            adCount++

            if (firstState.text.isEmpty() || secondState.text.isEmpty()) {
                emptyStateDialogOpened = true
            } else {
                // Check if the counter is a multiple of 3
                if (adCount % 3 == 0 && activity != null) {
                    showInterstialAd(activity, context)
                }
                viewModel.onEvent(MyEvent.SaveCar)
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: I tried, but now even it doesn't show any ads on my screen

Comment: Add a break point at the if statement and check the adcount value